# Completion Bar/Progress Udpate in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a massive spreadsheet where there are questions that need to be filled out on columns C through and AO. I am trying to set up an organization process where there is progress bar showing how many of these columns someone has filled out. This would be displayed in every row starting on B2. It can be either a percentage or a formatted bar that just shows progress or even tick marks, or a true and false formula might work I'm not sure.

I have tried conditional formatting, If Then, IsTEXT and more. I am kinda at a dead end and need this for a work project.

Comment: If `IF` and `ISTEXT` don't work, maybe some of the `COUNT`, `COUNTA`, `COUNTBLANK`, etc formulas would work to count how many of the columns have been filled out. Then you would just divide by 39 to get the percentage. Or you could use conditional formatting to do a quick progress bar, color scale, tick or cross, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I used the formula `=5-COUNTBLANK(B1:F1)` and used a data bar for conditional formatting, the result looks as follows:

[image]

You need to select all cells from "G1" to "G4" for the conditional formatting to know how to configure the data bar. (You need to have at least one full line in order to configure the maximum.)

Answer (score 0):

This formula returns the percentage of filled cells across a row from column C to AO. The result 0,102564 represents 10,2564 Percent.

```
=BYROW(C2:AO1000,LAMBDA(x,COUNTA(x)/39))
```

[image: Completion Bar/Progress Udpate in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

`=countifs( [row cells you're checking] , "<>"& "")/ [total # of columns to fill out]`

This formula will give the % completion. Then under conditional formatting, select "Data bars". Under "More Rules", set the minimum and maximum using the percent. This will default as 0 and 100, also check the box that says "Show Bar Only", then expand the column a bit so it's long enough to see the bar. For added precision, put the same formula next to this column, so you can see a status bar and the percentage adjacent to it.

If the amount of columns may change you can make that a formula by `COUNTA` on the columns headers (as long as they're not blank) like so:

`=countifs( [row cells you're checking] , "<>"& "")/ COUNTA( [column headers])`

It should look like this:

[image: This is how it would all look]